Finite dimensional vector subspace of coordinate ring that generates coordinate ring as a ring.
Ref:Weyman - An Introduction to Quiver Representations (2017)

Proposition 9.1.15. If $X$ is an affine $G$-variety, then there exists a representation $V$ and a closed $G$-equivariant closed immersion $\varphi: X \hookrightarrow V$.


Proof. Suppose that $G$ is an affine algebraic group acting regularly on an affine variety $X$. We can choose a finite dimensional subspace $W \subseteq \mathbb{C}[X]$ such that $W$ generates $\mathbb{C}[X]$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. Let $V=(G W)^{\star}$, the dual space of $G W$. If we choose a basis $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ of $G W$, then there is a unique $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphim
$$
\psi: \mathbb{C}\left[z_1, \ldots, z_n\right]=\mathbb{C}[V] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[X]
$$
such that the restriction of $\varphi$ to $G W$ is the inclusion $G W \subseteq \mathbb{C}[X]$. Since $W$ generates $\mathbb{C}[X]$, it is clear that $\psi$ is surjective. This ring homomorphism corresponds to a closed immersion $\varphi: X \hookrightarrow V$. The homomorphism $\psi$ is $G$-equivariant, so $\varphi$ is $G$-equivariant as well.

I dont understand the following which is a part of the proof:

We can choose a finite dimensional subspace $W \subseteq \mathbb{C}[X]$ such that $W$ generates $\mathbb{C}[X]$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.

Question:
How can you "choose" a finite dimensional $\mathbb C$ vector subspace $W$ of a coordinate ring $\mathbb C[X]$ for a affine variety $X$, such that $W$ generates as a ring the  $\mathbb C[X]$
Answer Since $\mathbb C[X]$ is finitely generated $\mathbb C$ algebra if I just take the generators $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and consider $W=\mathbb Cx_1,\cdots,\mathbb Cx_n$ is finite dimensional as a vector space but generates $\mathbb C[X]$ as a ring.
Is this correct?
Because consider $\mathbb C[X]=\mathbb C[x,y]/(x)\simeq \mathbb C[y]$ so if we take $W=\mathbb C  y\subset \mathbb C[y]$

Looks correct. Just take a subspace spanned by a (finite) set of generators of the algebra. By the way, from what book is this?

Weyman - An Introduction to Quiver Representations (2017)
